# Image lighbox and autoloading image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to autoload imagelightbox plugin by Osvaldas.

The problem is: how to start image lightbox presentation on page laod ?
Now, to start image viewing i must click image thumbnail.

This is my JS code:

```
var selectorG = 'a[data-imagelightbox="g"]';
    var instanceG = $(selectorG).imageLightbox({
    // show nav arrows
    onStart: function() {
    arrowsOn(instanceG, selectorG);
    closeButtonOn(instanceG);
    },
    // hide arrows
    onEnd: function() {
    arrowsOff();
    closeButtonOff();
    },
    // show loading image
    onLoadStart: function() {
    activityIndicatorOn();
    },
    // hide loading image
    onLoadEnd: function() {
    $('.imagelightbox-arrow').css('display', 'block');
    activityIndicatorOff();
    }
    });

/* This will autoload script, but with bug - events and images are cloned
$('a[data-imagelightbox="g"]').trigger('click');
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code fires a click event on every item with the attribute **data-imagelightbox="g"**. 
You have to find the very **first** ( "a[data-imagelightbox="g"].first()" https://api.jquery.com/first/ ) Element before trigger the click event.

Try the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-imagelightbox="g"]').first().trigger('click');
});
```